# Printing with desktop Javascript app

Tags: javascript, windows, desktop-application, javascript-framework

This question is theoretical one:

I've a lot of experience building web apps with ASP.NET, JSP and PHP. All of them were using either plain JavaScript or some of .js frameworks on the front end.

Now I have to work on one desktop app but based on Javascript. Now, the problem is that the app should have to print a lot of documents via thermal printer (similar to POS apps) and speed is the key request in this case! My previous experience with browsers says that this could be very slow on Windows.

Is it possible to make it fast just like with WPF app (which utilizes Win/.NET API and System.Printing and System.Windows namespaces)?

If yes, which framework would you suggest me to use - Electron.js, NW.js, Meteor or React desktop (or some other) and why?

Comment: This is a very broad question, but in a nutshell, there is no reason a Node-based app (regardless of framework) would be any slower than any native app. You may just have to make sure of the native APIs which can be done in a number of ways.

Comment: The problem is because the print workflow goes through the V8 engine! In WPF app after pressing print button it will start printing the document (similar to POS bills) after 0,2 seconds and when you do it in browser it is like few seconds.